# Read only the first file from a given image sequence path

Tags: python

I have an image sequence path that is as follows : `/host_server/master/images/set01a/env_basecolor_default_v001/basecolor_default.*.jpg`

1. In a pythonic way, is it possible for me to code and have it read the first file based on the above file path given?
2. If not, can I have it list the entire sequence of the sequence but only of that naming? Assuming that there is another sequence called `basecolor_default_beta.*.jpg`in the same directory

For #2, if I used `os.listdir('/host_server/master/images/set01a/env_basecolor_default_v001')`, it will be listing out files of the both image sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). Something like:

```
import glob
import os
path = '/host_server/master/images/set01a/env_basecolor_default_v001'
pattern = 'basecolor_default.*.jpg'
filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, pattern))
# read filenames[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution seems to be to use several functions.

1) To get ALL of the full filepaths, use

```
 main_path = "/host_server/master/images/set01a/env_basecolor_default_v001/"
 all_files = [os.path.join(main_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(main_path)]
```

2) To choose only those of a certain kind, use a filter.

```
beta_files = list(filter(lambda x: "beta" in x, all_files))
beta_files.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

> read the **first** file based on the above file path given?

With effective [**`glob.iglob(pathname, recursive=False)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) (if you need the name/path of the 1st found file):

```
import glob

path = '/host_server/master/images/set01a/env_basecolor_default_v001/basecolor_default.*.jpg'
it = glob.iglob(path)
first = next(it)
```

---

> `glob.iglob()` - Return an iterator which yields the same values as
>   `glob()` without actually storing them all simultaneously.